# Unknown identifier with custom named columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I guess its pretty easy to solve but I don't get it:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(PERS_NR) AS Spieler1, TO_NUMBER(PERS_NR) AS Spieler2 
FROM DBS_TAB_MITARBEITER 
WHERE Spieler1 < Spieler2;
```

I get an

> unkown identifier

error in the `where` clause. Why?

Comment: Your query will return no rows, because a number is never strictly less than itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `where` clause doesn't work since the fields aren't know at that moment yet. You have to use the real column names:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(PERS_NR) AS Spieler1, TO_NUMBER(PERS_NR) AS Spieler2 
FROM DBS_TAB_MITARBEITER 
WHERE TO_NUMBER(PERS_NR) < TO_NUMBER(PERS_NR);
```

When you do that, you immediately see that your query doesn't yield any rows since the `where` clause is impossible to result in a `true`.

Comment: @Thanks. Can't help it :)